# SQL Count Numbers of Projects started Each Day Between Two Dates

Tags: sql, date, count

I have this table that I need count how many projects (job) i have started each day.

```
job   start          end
1   01-01-2013     04-01-2013
2   01-01-2013     02-01-2013
3   01-01-2013     03-01-2013
4   03-01-2013     04-01-2013
5   03-01-2013     04-01-2013
6   03-01-2013     04-01-2013
...
```

i want count how many job's i have started each day.. / **i mean how many job's are open each day..**

```
date           count
01-01-2013       3
02-01-2013       3
03-01-2013       5    
04-01-2013       4
05-01-2013       0
...
```

Comment: And what have you tried yet?

Comment: What rdbms are you using?

Comment: That appears to be a count of how many jobs are *active* each day, rather than the ones *started* on each day (since then the answer seems to be 3 on the 1st and 3rd and 0 on all other days)

Comment: Also, what database system are you using, and do you already have a calendar table available?

Answer (score 2):

```
select start, count(*) as jobs_per_day
from your_table
group by start
```

But this will not return a record for dates where you did not create any job.

Comment: Adding a `WHERE end < '01-01-2014'` assuming that's the end date.

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me in postgresql

```
with dates as (
  select aday::date
  from generate_series((select min(start) from your_table),
                       (select max(end) from your_table),
                       '1 day'::interval) aday
), flat as (
  select * 
  from dates, your_table 
  where dates.aday between your_table.start and your_table.end
)

select
  aday,
  count(*) as count

from flat

group by aday

order by aday
;
```

The first CTE generates a series of dates, which might have to be done differently in another RDBMS.

Answer (score -1):

select start as date, count(*) as count from table_name
where start_date>="your start date" and end_date<="your end date"
group by start;

Comment: This will not give the output he's looking for since it's only checking for one specific start and end date.